# CMake how to collect auto generated source and header files

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

To put a bit of context first, I'm trying to decouple a repo that includes protobuf definitions as well as proto-using entities. I want to create a repo with only protobuf definitions and scripts that export the resulting classes in different languages, to be imported by other projects that use them.

Generating protobuf classes in c++ is actually quite simple (few lines of python script), but after that it gets tricky. You end up with an unorganized set of source files. I want to use CMake to collect all of the files and generate the library. The file structure should look something like this:

```
/root
    /proto-package-1
        foo.pb.h
        foo.pb.cc
    /proto-package-2
        /proto-package-3
            bar.pb.h
            bar.pb.cc
        bazz.pb.h
        bazz.pb.cc
```

I'm a bit of a noob in CMake but I've read that it is good practice to explicitly list all the source files in the CMakeLists.txt file. But I'd like to make the generation of this c++ library to be fully automatic. Would that be a good reason to violate this rule? And what CMake commands can help me out?

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project ("CMakeProject1")
set(TARGET_NAME CMakeProject1)

# Include sub-projects.
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

add_library(${TARGET_NAME} STATIC 
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/root/proto-package-1/foo.pb.h
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/root/proto-package-1/foo.pb.cc
//This is not going to cut it. Cannot add a proto and auto-generate.
)
```

Comment: You are aware of [protobuf_generate_cpp](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindProtobuf.html#command:protobuf_generate_cpp) function, which generates files using protobuf, aren't you? This function assignes output variable with paths of files generated, so all you need is to use this variable in `add_library` call.

Comment: Questions: Is that CMake module liked, maintained and used? Does it compile .proto files as well as assign it to targets? And if so, how can I specify what version of protoc to use?

Comment: It was last updated ten days ago. There is a (sadly undocumented) mode where it inspects the sources of a target and adds rules to add protoc-generated files to the target. As for the protoc version, you can try passing a required version to the find_package command.

Comment: I will try to make it work (which is a pain in windows). It looks like it really was made with the idea to include the proto definitions in the same repo, opposite of what I'm trying

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate them in the cmake and create a list of generated files

```
# Get list of .proto files
file(GLOB_RECURSE proto_files RELATIVE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} "*.proto")

## Get Protobuf include dirs
get_target_property(protobuf_dirs protobuf::libprotobuf INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
foreach(dir IN LISTS protobuf_dirs)
  if ("${dir}" MATCHES "BUILD_INTERFACE")
    message(STATUS "Adding proto path: ${dir}")
    list(APPEND PROTO_DIRS "--proto_path=${dir}")
  endif()
endforeach()

# Generate Protobuf cpp sources
set(PROTO_HDRS)
set(PROTO_SRCS)
foreach(PROTO_FILE IN LISTS proto_files)
  #message(STATUS "protoc proto(cc): ${PROTO_FILE}")
  get_filename_component(PROTO_DIR ${PROTO_FILE} DIRECTORY)
  get_filename_component(PROTO_NAME ${PROTO_FILE} NAME_WE)
  set(PROTO_HDR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROTO_DIR}/${PROTO_NAME}.pb.h)
  set(PROTO_SRC ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROTO_DIR}/${PROTO_NAME}.pb.cc)
  #message(STATUS "protoc hdr: ${PROTO_HDR}")
  #message(STATUS "protoc src: ${PROTO_SRC}")
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${PROTO_SRC} ${PROTO_HDR}
    COMMAND protobuf::protoc
    "--proto_path=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    ${PROTO_DIRS}
    "--cpp_out=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
    ${PROTO_FILE}
    DEPENDS ${PROTO_FILE} protobuf::protoc
    COMMENT "Generate C++ protocol buffer for ${PROTO_FILE}"
    VERBATIM)
  list(APPEND PROTO_HDRS ${PROTO_HDR})
  list(APPEND PROTO_SRCS ${PROTO_SRC})
endforeach()

# [optional] Create a library of all generated C++ files
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_proto ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_proto PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_proto PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_proto PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_proto PROPERTIES CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_proto PRIVATE
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
  $<TARGET_PROPERTY:protobuf::libprotobuf,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
  )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_proto PRIVATE protobuf::libprotobuf)
```

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/a0a56698ba8fd07b7f84aee4fc45d891a8cd9828/cmake/cpp.cmake#L234-L294

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use an [internal function of the FindProtobuf package](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake) to generate static libraries containing protobuf implementations:

```
find_package(Protobuf 3.12 REQUIRED)
add_library(protopackage1 STATIC proto-package-1/foo.proto)
protobuf_generate(LANGUAGE cpp TARGET protopackage1)
```

You can pass extra arguments to `protobuf_generate` but you will have to figure out how protobuf_generate_cpp passes them.

Comment: That could be the function I was looking for. Super handy that they included it with clear documentation on how to use it.

Comment: You could always raise an issue about it or even submit a doc patch; maybe they simply have not considered your use case yet. As they say: "patches welcome"